# System.IO effects on OS's file system performance in C#

Tags: c#

Is there any performance or any kind of effect on OS's file system permission between the codes below:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"file.dat", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
// and
FileStream fs = File.Create(@"file.dat");
```

PS: except the usage of a static function issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to reflector, `File.Create(path)` is just:

```
new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None, 4096, FileOptions.None);
```

and `new FileStream(@"file.dat", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)` also gets the 4096 buffer - so no, it is just the `FileAccess.ReadWrite` which is different.

And I don't think `FileAccess.Write` is much better than `FileAccess.ReadWrite` because they both locks the file - but I may be wrong.

*to comment:* because `FileShare` is set to `None` and it is write access you want they properly (=I don't know for sure) ain't much of a difference. However, if you wanted `Read` access the `new FileStream(path, mode, access)` approach is different because `FileShare` is set to `Read` as a default. However, in this case you want to create a file, and therefore it does not make much sense to only read ;-)

Comment: Ok, I decompiled the code with reflector too before asking the question.. but I was wondering if there is any performance difference between FileAccess.Write and FileAccess.ReadWrite methods in OS side? (I just got a problem with Win7 file system that's why I'm asking...)

Comment: @Bora see update :-) Not really want your looked for, though.

Answer (score 2):

If I recall correctly, `File.Create("file.dat")` just wraps a call to `new FileStream("file.dat", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)`.